# iCAL event on the last day of the Month

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

I need to create an event that falls on the last day of the month. If that day is a weekend I would like the event to show on the previous Friday. Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the immediate answer, more generic solutions can be found by reading the [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)

What you say is that you want an event that happens with a given recurrence
which is detailed in the [event recurrence rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10), which defines the property `RRULE` for the components `VEVENT` as well as others (`VALARM`, `VTODO`) as well as the associated properties

So:

> RRULE

on a monthly basis

> RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;

on a weekday:

> RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;

only the last working day of the month

> RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1